# S3 uploads thru angular

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3

Using [this plugin](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload)

Sooooo ive got a problem

So, i am generating a signed S3 url on my server, and attempting to upload using this plugin. I can generate the url and upload a file using

How its worked before

`shell
curl -T file.jpg http://bla.s3.amazon.com/blahbahbla`

How im doing it

When I attempt to upload the file from the browser like this

```javascript

```
$upload.http({
   url:    decodeURIComponent(data.signed_url),
   method: 'PUT',
   data:   file,
   headers: {
    'Content-Type':file.type,
   }
}).progress(function(evt) {

    console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));

}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    console.log(data);

}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    console.warn(data, status);

});
```

```

Response

I get a response like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><StringToSignBytes>50 55 54 0a 0a 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 6a 70 65 67 0a 31 34 35 32 38 37 39 36 38 36 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 61 63 6c 3a 70 75 62 6c 69 63 2d 72 65 61 64 0a 2f 62 67 70 72 6f 6f 66 2f 66 61 63 65 62 6f 6f 6b 3a 31 30 30 30 30 33 34 37 31 35 37 34 31 30 35 2f 33 65 31 62 36 64 32 39 2d 62 66 34 31 2d 34 37 62 31 2d 61 35 31 33 2d 30 38 38 61 39 63 30 32 61 39 62 63 2e 6a 70 67</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>CE628CB59F561A3D</RequestId><HostId>u5iLkvYLE0hRj30IU+qMS+XiwlwY/VXt8ZACxyot2KDwnLw5S2HL/pGgk4F/nHfr</HostId><SignatureProvided>hJg fYN2h6qz9jJATt4Zp A C94=</SignatureProvided><StringToSign>PUT

image/jpeg
1452879686
x-amz-acl:public-read
/kirkstrobeck/facebook:100003471574105/3e1b6d29-bf41-47b1-a513-088a9c02a9bc.jpg</StringToSign><AWSAccessKeyId>MY_ACCESS_KEY</AWSAccessKeyId></Error>
```

Here are the headers for both requests

Req Headers

```
PUT /facebook:100003471574105/3e1b6d29-bf41-47b1-a513-088a9c02a9bc.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=MY_ACCESS_KEY&Expires=1452879686&Signature=hJg+fYN2h6qz9jJATt4Zp+A+C94=&x-amz-acl=public-read HTTP/1.1
Host: kirkstrobeck.s3.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 362867
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:5005
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Referer: http://localhost:5005/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Res Headers

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Max-Age: 10000
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-request-id: CE628CB59F561A3D
x-amz-id-2: u5iLkvYLE0hRj30IU+qMS+XiwlwY/VXt8ZACxyot2KDwnLw5S2HL/pGgk4F/nHfr
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 15 Jan 2014 05:41:26 GMT
Connection: close
Server: AmazonS3
```

---

This is how we are generating the signed putObject url in NodeJS

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var AWS  = require('aws-sdk');
var s3   = new AWS.S3({
    apiVersion:      '2014-01-10',
    accessKeyId:     'AWS_ACCESS_KEY',
    secretAccessKey: 'AWS_SEC_ACCESS_KEY'
});


module.exports =  function (req, res, next) {
    var exten   = req.param('ext');
    var expire  = req.param('expire');

    var key = uuid.v4() + exten;
    var params  = {
        Bucket:  'BUCKET_NAME',
        Key:     key,
        Expires: 900,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    };

    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, url){
        // ..  handle callback
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html, it looks like your's using the query string method of authentication, so your request must be of the form

```
GET /my-bucket/foo
 ?Signature=<urlencode(base64(hmac-sha1(VERB + "\n" + CONTENT-MD5 + "\n" + CONTENT-TYPE + "\n" + Expires + "\n" + CanonicalizedAmzHeaders + "\n" + CanonicalizedResource)))>
 &Expires=<seconds since epoch>
 &AWSAccessKeyId=<aws-id>
```

Addressing each of these, comparing how you generate the signed request with the request itself

VERB: According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/frames.html using 'putObject' is the correct way to request signing a PUT request. Your request headers seem to use a PUT request.

CONTENT-MD5: You haven't specified a `ContentMD5` option when signing your request on the server. According to the docs this is optional, but an empty string + new line must be included in the string for which the signature is calculated. So you might need to add an empty `ContentMD5` parameter to the `params` object passed to `getSignedUrl`

CONTENT-TYPE: `ContentType` is also optional. However, I note you are sending the ContentType header in the PUT request, but not specifying it when generating the signature. So the S3 may use this to generate the signature to check against, and fail the request. I suggest either setting the ContentType when generating the signature to what it will be in the browser, or make it empty in both cases (probably passing an empty string to the call to `getSignedUrl`

Expires: From the docs:

> The Expires field is given as the number of seconds since epoch time

I'm not sure how the Node API uses the `Expires` option, but setting it as 900 might mean it has already expired. The url you've written has it output as 1452879686, which is on January 20th 2014. Given your question was written on January 15th/17th, I'm not sure how this matches up. I would check exactly what you need to pass as `Expires`, and try passing a full date to the call to 'getSignedUrl'.

CanonicalizedAmzHeaders: From what I can see, the call to `getSignedUrl` added `x-amz-acl=public-read`, so I can only assume it used it when generating the url.

CanonicalizedResource: Again I can only assume that the call to `getSignedUrl` is using this correctly.

AWSAccessKeyId: It's in the URL generated, so I assume getSignedUrl used it correctly.

In summary:

- ContentMD5: Set it to the empty string in the `params` object
- Make sure ContentType is specified  when generating the signature, and make it the same as for the PUT request (or empty or `image/jpeg`)
- Set a full date as the `Expires` option to the params object `getSignedUrl`, and check the generated URL that this is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

This example can maybe help:
https://github.com/bookingbricks/file-upload-example
Using: Node, aws-sdk-js, jQuery-file-upluad (blueimp)

Server:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey:     AWS_SECRET_KEY});
AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-1';

app.post('/s', function (req, res) {
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {Bucket: 'BUCKETNAME', Key: req.body.name, ContentType: req.body.type};
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function(err, url) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        res.json({url: url});
    });
});
```

Client:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/s',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {name: file.name, size: file.size, type:file.type},
}).success(function(res){
    $.ajax({
        url: res.url,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: file,
        processData: false,
        contentType: file.type,
    }).success(function(res){
        console.log('Done');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

S3 has very specific requirements for uploading files via POST. There are specific input fields that require values that appear to be missing from your request.

Check out the docs for the required fields: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html

Comment: See the update above about how we are generating the signed putObject url in NodeJS

Comment: If it's coming from a web browser, historically you've needed to use POST because the entire flow is different from a server-side call. Having said that, there is a Developer Preview of the [AWS SDK for Browsers](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforbrowser/) that may simplify some of the stuff you're trying to do client-side.